# How to find min/max of class properties and return its object?

Tags: kotlin

I have some class objects

```
class City (val name: String) {
    var degrees: Int = 0
}
```

```
val city1 = City("city1")
city1.degrees = 10
val city2 = City("city2")
city2.degrees = 20
val city3 = City("city3")
city3.degrees = 30
```

How to find min/max of degrees of 3 cities and return it's object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them in a list (or other iterable) and then use [minByOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by-or-null.html) or [maxByOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html):

```kotlin
val cityWithMaxDegrees = listOf(city1, city2, city3).maxByOrNull { it.degrees }
```

Note that if the list is empty, `maxByOrNull` will return null, so you would have to handle it. This is *also* the case for the deprecated `maxBy`/`minBy`, which is the reason why they have been deprecated. In the future, `maxBy`/`minBy` can be reintroduced with non-null return types and throwing exceptions in case of empty list.